# how to build web can run python code to get data from file .owl

Tags: python, web, ontology

i am working with ontology 
i created data(.owl) and query by python
next step . I need to build my own web can get input is a sparql and result will be displayed on web . my database is only file .owl
thanks all

Answer (score 0):

[RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#) is a Python library that can parse an OWL file and query it with both SPARQL and Python.

[Here's an old app I made](https://github.com/PaulBrownMagic/SemanticFlask) that seems to be the same use-case. It uses RDFLib, can read local OWL files and provides a SPARQL query interface via Flask to an end user. Hopefully it'll give you a head-start or useful reference.